# In html input label * add detect to required field using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image]

I have multiple input form but need to * to add in label, not manually add using javascript

```
 <label for="form_name">Firstname</label>
    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname" required="">
```

Comment: You can't even add classes to the labels?

Answer (score 1):

Add a CSS class first and then add it to your input

```js
$('input[required]').each(function(){
      $($(this).parent()).find('label').addClass('required') //depending on the structure of your fields
});
```

```css
.required:after{
    color:red;
    content:" * ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="form_name">First name</label>
    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required="">
```

Comment: You are making assumptions on the DOM structure which OP's input doesn't clearly support so far. Also I don't think using JS for the job is the best solution here where it can easily be achieved using CSS.

Comment: connexo you are right, my bad I should have mentioned it

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order of the elements (and correct the positioning using CSS), this allows for using the adjacent sibling combinator `+`:

```css
.form-group { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "label"
    "input";
}

:required+label::after { content: " *"; color: teal; }

.form-group label { grid-area: label; }
.form-group .form-control { grid-area: input; }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname" required="">
  <label for="form_name">Firstname</label>
</div>
```

Comment: can order change label then input

Comment: The HTML order must be the label *following* the input, otherwise CSS alone cannot help you. For the **visual** order, you can use CSS, like my example shows. If you have no control over the HTML, you must resort to Javascript.